# Getting error "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.'' after db.commit()

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to save a *list* of links, titles, etc for my rss feeder, but when I commit it it gives an error.

Here's my Python code:

```
class News(db.Model):
         __tablename__ = 'rssfeeds'
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        links = db.Column(db.String(60), unique = True, nullable = False)
        titles = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True, nullable = False)
        summarys = db.Column(db.Text, unique = True, nullable = False)
        contents = db.Column(db.Text, unique = True, nullable = False)

#Dummy data
my_links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
my_titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
my_summary = ['summary1', 'summary2', 'summary3']
my_content = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3']
```

Here are the sql queries

My flask-SQLAlchemy code:

```
#importing python lists

feed = News(links = my_links, titles = my_titles, summarys = my_summarys)
db.session.add(feed)
db.session.commit()   #here is where i get the error
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
......
.....
_execute_context
        self._handle_dbapi_exception(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        util.raise_(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
        raise exception
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
        self.dialect.do_execute(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 593, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: rssfeeds
    [SQL: INSERT INTO rssfeeds (links, titles, summarys, contents) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
    [parameters: (['link1', 'link2', 'link3'], ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'], ['summary1', 'summary2', 'summary3'], ['content1', 'content2', 'content3'])]
    (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you haven't **created** your database.

You need to run `db.create_all` on your database session before you can **commit** any changes to it.

Also, I doubt you can save a list the way you are doing it. It is sure to raise an error.

**EDIT:**

```
class News(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rssfeeds'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    link = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    summary = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

#Dummy data
my_links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
my_titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
my_summary = ['summary1', 'summary2', 'summary3']
my_content = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3']

for feed_data in zip(my_links, my_titles, my_summary, my_content):
    feed = News(links=feed_data[0], titles=feed_data[1], summary=feed_data[2], content=feed_data[3])
    db.session.add(feed)

db.session.commit()
```

Comment: @Neverless_child I did run it. I just forgot to mention it here. (I'm really sorry)

Comment: Then it's probably like the error message said. "... probably unsupported type."

Comment: It's not possible to add a list to your database the way you are doing it.

Comment: @Neverless_child So, do you have any idea how I ought to do it. I've been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: I'm guessing what you want to do is to store the properties of each RSS feeder (link, title, etc) to your database.

Comment: I want to store the links, titles... that I get from scraping the web page. There are multiple links, titles... so the only good option is store it into a list, and then add it to database.

Comment: I could do it manually but that's a _lot_ of work.

Comment: check my edit. is this what you want to do?

Comment: I tried running your edit, but it gave an NameError when I query it.                        
Anyway, thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

`sqlite` dialect [does not support `String` type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-data-types).

Use `Text(lenght=60)` instead when defining your models.